# AngularJS : How do I bind ng-model to an array inside a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I can't seem to make my multiple dropdowns to work.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4] track by $index">
    <select ng-model="myArray[i]" ng-options="someList"></select>
</div>
```

In the html the result is ... ng-model="myArray[i] instead of ng-model="myArray[0] etc.

I have tried curly brackets but it doesn't work. closest thing was ng-model="myArray['{{ i }}'] but that' not really what I want.

Edit: Here is a fiddle to illustrate.

http://jsfiddle.net/dpkzzyug/1/

You need to examine the HTML to see that the result literally writes out i (or $index in this case) instead of the value.

Comment: This is pretty difficult to understand where the problem is.
Two things: One: add a Fiddle please.
            Two: why are you calling myArray[i]? I assume you mean just {{i}}

Comment: Use myArray[$index]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the html will write out i / $index even though the logics of angular still work. I was having problems elsewhere and thought it was because of this.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you have works, but the problem is that `myArray` is local to the `ng-repeat` scope.  You need to make sure that `myArray` exists outside of this scope.

Something like the following will work:

```
<div ng-app ng-init="someList=[1,2,3]; myArray = []">
    <div ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4] track by $index">
        <select ng-model="myArray[i]" ng-options="i for i in someList"></select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/778x0pm0/1/

I would personally prefer to use the `controller as` syntax since this makes this a little clearer:

```
<div ng-app=app ng-init="someList=[1,2,3]">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl as ctrl">
        <div ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4] track by $index">
            <select ng-model="ctrl.myArray[i]" ng-options="i for i in someList"></select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/778x0pm0/